# replace trailing periods with spaces

Tags: regex, r

I have a strange request with regex in R.  I have vector of character strings where some have multiple trailing periods.  I want to replace these periods with spaces.  The example and desired outcome should make clear what I'm after (maybe I need to attack it with what I give to replace argument rather than the pattern argument of `gsub`):

**Example and attempts:**

```
x <- c("good", "little.bad", "really.ugly......")
gsub("\\.$", " ", x)
  #produces this
  #[1] "good"              "little.bad"        "really.ugly..... "
gsub("\\.+$", " ", x)
  #produces this
  #[1] "good"         "little.bad"   "really.ugly "
```

**Desired outcome**

```
[1] "good"              "little.bad"        "really.ugly      "
```

So the original vector (x) had the last string with 6 periods at the end so I'd like 6 spaces without touching the period between really and ugly.  I know the `$` looks at the end but can't get past this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
gsub("\\.(?=\\.*$)", " ", mystring, perl=TRUE)
```

**Explanation:**

```
\.   # Match a dot
(?=  # only if followed by
 \.* # zero or more dots
 $   # until the end of the string
)    # End of lookahead assertion.
```

Comment: I'm getting `invalid regular expression '\.(?=\.*$)', reason 'Invalid regexp'`

Comment: @DavidRobinson: Inside a string, you need to double the backslashes.

Comment: @Andrie: Thanks; I moved your edit up into the original answer. Not much sense leaving the incomplete code standing there.

Comment: I'm getting that error even with your double backslashed version, until you added perl=TRUE. Now it's good

Comment: Ah - you need the perl=TRUE in there.  That's what I was missing when translating to R.

Comment: @DavidRobinson: It was actually Andrie who found this omission and fixed it. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: Tim elegant and a terrific explanation of the regex solution.  IMHO this could be an example of a good regex explanation

Comment: I'm not getting why the replacement works here (replacement string is 1 char). Is it because (in a sense) it recursively replaces a `.` with a ` ` until it fails the match? (+1 Very nice solution by the way; my brain just doesn't understand it it is that clever!)

Comment: @GavinSimpson: No recursion is involved here. First the `\.` matches any dot. Then the lookahead expression `(?=...)` "looks ahead" in the string to see if the regex contained inside it *could* be matched here. But it doesn't actually advance the regex engine inside the string. So in this case a dot is only matched if nothing but dots follows until the end of the string. And then the next dot is matched and replaced, and then the next...

Comment: @TimPietzcker Thanks that is very clear, and how I was thinking it might work but didn't explain it well enough in my comment. (Probably should have used "recursively" instead as I didn't mean it in the usual sense.)

Answer (score 2):

While I waited for a regex solution that makes sense I decided to come up with a nonsensical way to solve this:

```
messy.sol <- function(x) {
paste(unlist(list(gsub("\\.+$", "", x), 
    rep(" ", nchar(x) -  nchar(gsub("\\.+$", "", x))))),collapse="")
}

sapply(x, messy.sol, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
```

I'd say Tim's is a bit prettier :)

Answer (score 2):

Tim's solution is clearly better but I figured I'd try my hand at an alternate way.  Using liberal use of `regmatches` helps us out here

```
x <- c("good", "little.bad", "really.ugly......")
# Get an object with 'match data' to feed into regmatches
# Here we match on any number of periods at the end of a string
out <- regexpr("\\.*$", x)

# On the right hand side we extract the pieces of the strings
# that match our pattern with regmatches and then replace
# all the periods with spaces.  Then we use assignment
# to store that into the spots in our strings that match the
# regular expression.
regmatches(x, out) <- gsub("\\.", " ", regmatches(x, out))
x
#[1] "good"              "little.bad"        "really.ugly      "
```

So not quite as clean as a single regular expression.  But I've never really gotten around to learning those 'lookahead's in perl regular expressions.

Comment: not as clean as Tim's but still a good solution (particularly in comparison to my own). +1